# iOS 11: Force UIWebView to use cache (NSURLCache) when offline

Tags: caching, uiwebview, ios11, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

Since iOS 11, when the device is offline, network requests are most often fail quickly with a [“The Internet connection appears to be offline.” error message (code -1009)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrornotconnectedtointernet?language=objc). Previously – as was the case for iOS version < 11 – request would first try and go through (parts of) the URL loading system.

To serve content to `UIWebViews` while offline, I rely on a custom subclass of `NSURLCache`, that returns cached data first, and requests the actual resource from the server afterwards in the background (only if needed/updated), to store for the *next* request.

**I would like to force my app – particular my `UIWebView`s I’d like to work offline – to still go through the URL loading system, so that my custom `NSURLCache` is asked for a cached response every time (as was the case before iOS 11). Is this possible?**

#### More background

While the request attempt fails immediately on iOS 11 when the device doesn’t have an internet connection, the OS also introduced the [`waitsForConnectivity`-flag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/2908812-waitsforconnectivity?language=objc#) to `NSURLSession`. This does exactly what I want. However, this only works for my simpler requests that load a single file and that I was able to easily port from a `NSURLConnection`-request to a `NSURLSession`-request.

`UIWebView` still uses NSURLConnection, and so I can’t use `NSURLSession` and `waitsForConnectivity`. But: is there another way to force going through the URL loading system and hit my custom `NSURLCache` implementation?

In my web views, I simply request pages like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“some/url.html" relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“https://www.example.com/"]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

So, the above used to work and still works for iOS versions < 11. No luck with iOS 11.
I tried several values for the `cachePolicy` parameter, including `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad`. Still no luck.

And it’s not as simple as loading/requesting a single HTML file. The pages have lots of resources: CSS files, JS, images etc. And this was all transparently cached by my custom `NSURLCache`. Sadly no more with iOS 11.

(Now: I’m using a custom subclass of `NSURLCache` in the first place, because I couldn’t rely on the standard `NSURLCache` implementation, no matter what configuration and `cachePolicy` settings. If anyone has a suggestion for a different solution (without a custom `NSURLCache`) to my problem, I’m definitely listening.)